# R: Generate data from a probability density distribution

Tags: r, random, probability-density

Say I have a simple array, with a corresponding probability distribution.

```
library(stats)    
data <- c(0,0.08,0.15,0.28,0.90)
pdf_of_data <- density(data, from= 0, to=1, bw=0.1)
```

Is there a way I could generate another set of data using the same distribution. As the operation is probabilistic, it need not exactly match the initial distribution anymore, but will be just generated from it.

I did have success finding a simple solution on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best bet is to generate the empirical cumulative density function, approximate the inverse, and then transform the input.

The compound expression looks like

```
random.points <- approx(
  cumsum(pdf_of_data$y)/sum(pdf_of_data$y),
  pdf_of_data$x,
  runif(10000)
)$y
```

Yields

```
hist(random.points, 100)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! I'm going to add it to the `stackoverflow` package.

Comment: You might want to look at the `ecdf` function. It does much of that for you.

Comment: @42- I don't see how the `ecdf` function helps in this case.  We have a pdf, which we can integrate (with `cumsum`) to get a cdf, which we invert to get a quantile function, which we can then draw from.  `ecdf` generates a cdf from data drawn from a distribution.

Answer (score 9):

From the examples in the documentation of `?density` you (almost) get the answer.

So, something like this should do it:

```
library("stats")    
data <- c(0,0.08,0.15,0.28,0.90)
pdf_of_data <- density(data, from= 0, to=1, bw=0.1)

# From the example.
N <- 1e6
x.new <- rnorm(N, sample(data, size = N, replace = TRUE), pdf_of_data$bw)

# Histogram of the draws with the distribution superimposed.
hist(x.new, freq = FALSE)
lines(pdf_of_data)
```

[image: Imgur]

You can just reject the draws outside your interval as in [rejection sampling.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Algorithm)
Alternatively, you can use the algorithm described in the link.

Comment: Isn't this just adding gaussian noise to the data, not drawing from the smoothed density curve?

Comment: @NealFultz Remember that the smoothed density curve is a mixture of Gaussian distributions---one for each observation. So we're just sampling directly from each component. But yes, you're also right.

Comment: @NealFultz Right. But I guess it's easily modified by using the proper function instead of `rnorm`.

Comment: Thanks, this is really great! I guess rejection sampling would look like this: 
`expected_sample_size <- 2;
new_sample <- list();
while(length(new_sample) < expected_sample_size ){
new_item <- rnorm(1, sample(data, size = 1, replace = TRUE), data_pdf$bw);
if(new_item >0 & new_item < 1){ new_sample[length(new_sample)+1] <- new_item}
}
`

Comment: With this approach there is one limitation though in that if the original distribution predicts 0 chance for some number, the new sample might still  contain it as the variation is added after the probability density distribution is used. It seems to me.

Answer (score 4):

To draw from the curve:

```
sample(pdf_of_data$x, 1e6, TRUE, pdf_of_data$y)
```

Comment: Note, that this approach is strongly dependent on the `n` argument in `density`. You'll never get more than `n` unique values. You're just sampling from a discrete probability function with `n` values and corresponding probabilities. Depending on your application, this might be just fine.

Comment: That's a good point, and `n` might be manipulated to fit the data. For my purposes this actually works too. Too many correct and useful answers to choose from here. Many thanks again!