# R sample based on the distribution of an input vector

Tags: r, simulation

I have a vector of numbers called **data** with length 3205.

```
head(data,20)
 [1]  225.43200   29.20875  329.46792   22.70996
 [5]   80.84970  374.23959  343.11610  319.04798
 [9] 2477.73200   72.79434   30.53376   92.39412
[13]   47.70744   52.30388  339.59634 1177.00448
[17]   48.27329  541.80997   38.45772 1568.93400
```

The density plot of this data looks like the following:

```
plot(density(data))
```

[image]

I would like to randomly sample a number given the distribution of this vector. Most of the times the number picked will be under 1000 but there is also a small chance of it being 1000-3000, and if we were to plot the density of the resultant sampled vector it would end up looking the same as this density plot. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: This question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871602/r-generate-data-from-a-probability-density-distribution).

Comment: Interesting. Not sure if there‘s a way to extract some required info from the density object itself. But what you could do is to define an arbitrary numer of cut/break points of your vector (e.g. split the range into 100 groups), count how many values are within each group, divide that by the numer of total data points and use that information as the probability argument in R‘s sample function. The inputted vector would be the range of numbers in each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer in Stackoverflow link given in a comment proposes to use the empirical *cdf* to perform the inverse sampling method. This is correct but there's a simplest way to achieve the same result: just pick some elements at random from the vector, with replacement.

Another possibility is to sample from a continuous distribution fitted to the distribution of your vector, using the **kde1d** package:

```r
library(kde1d)
fit <- kde1d(data)
simulations <- rkde1d(1000, fit)
```